# 3-phase induction motor starting current calculation

Tags: current, motor, induction

[image]

I'm trying to calculate the starting current of a motor (460 VAC @ 60 Hz) using the datasheet information I shared. Am I suppose to use the ratio given under "starting values" for current?

Is it like since the current ratio is 8.9 given for wye connection, I multiply rated current 4.4 A with 8.9 and the starting current is about 39.16 A? Can anyone make comments? By the way, this motor is used with an oil pump.

Comment: The one mystery is why they would split the STARTING VALUES columns in Y & Δ.

Comment: @greybeard why is that a mystery? The starting current in Y is lower than the starting current in Δ. Before motor starters and VFDs were around, it was common to start large motors in Y first, then switch to Δ when they were up to speed.

Comment: @KristoferA Those columns contain ratios of (ratios of) currents&moments: Why would these depend on configuration?

Answer (score 0):

According to my research, most textbooks and motor documentation say that the starting current of an induction motor can be up to 5-7 times of the rated motor current. However, I recently measured using an energy analyzer and saw that the highest current draw was about 5,7A or so (nominal current is 4,3A) at the start.

This is quite a complicated topic. So it is hard to determine the starting current theoretically.